# Using expression trees with EF Core produces strange SQL statements

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I am using expression trees to dynamically build my expression at runtime, which is then used in the `.Where()` clause of `IQueryable<T>`, as I call my database. The resulting SQL statement looks extremely strange for me and I do not understand what is going on there.

General Information: Project uses Framework 4.7.2, EF Core 3.1.3 NuGet

Example (following is simplified):

Consider a customer Class like this:

```
public class Customer{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
}
```

The DBContext is set up properly with `DBSet<Customer>` and so on.

So now I want to use something like `... db.Customer.Where(expression).ToList() ...` where I have to build the corresponding expression at runtime. The program will be given the list of search criteria to use for that like `List<(string, string)>` where the first string will be the name of the property of customer and the second is the value to use for filtering. This way of passing the search criteria **can not** be changed.

I build my expression tree like this, having converted the list of search criteria to dictionary (`Dictionary<string, List<string>>`) with property name as key and list of values of actual values to search for. typesDictionary holds the information about property types (name -> string, etc.):

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "c");
var andList = new List<Expression>();

foreach (var sc in searchCriteria){
    var orList = new List<Expression>();
    foreach (var value in sc.Value{
       var expr = Expression.Equal(
       Expression.Property(param, sc.Key),
       Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(value, typesDictionary[sc.Key]), typesDictionary[sc.Key]));
       orList.Add(expr);
     }
     andList.Add(orList.Aggregate(Expression.Or));
}
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(andList.Aggregate(Expression.And), param);
```

Resulting expression looks like `c => ((c.Name == "Bob") OR (c.Name == "John")) AND (c.Age == 12)` for example. A bit of an exessive use of parentheses...

Concerning SQL I would expect it to be something like:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.Age, c.Address
FROM someDB.someSchema.Customers as c
WHERE c.Name = "John" OR c.Name = "Bob" AND c.Age = 13
```

But what gets created is something like:

```
SELECT [c].[Name], [c].[Aage], [c].[Address]
      FROM [Customer] AS [c]
      WHERE ((CASE
          WHEN [c].[Age] = CAST(12 AS int) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
      END | CASE
          WHEN [c].[Age] = CAST(15 AS int) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
      END) | CASE
          WHEN [c].[Age] = CAST(22 AS int) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
      END) = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

What is going on here? Where do all the `CASE WHEN` and `CASTS` come from?

Comment: You probably need to give exact examples rather than "something like" as the differences in parentheses could be affecting things. The actual example appears to be creating a truth-table of sorts which would possibly indicate that the ints (12, 15 & 22) are the IDs of the Johns & Bobs with ages of 13? Adding more detail (e.g. source table for customer) with more accuracy might make the problem clearer.

Comment: But at the end of the day, does it work/ is it performant/ does it have any red flags in its execution plan? I wouldn't really care so much what an SQL looks like, only what it executes like; the optimizer will practically rewrite it all anyway

Comment: @CaiusJard Good point. I was assuming that the `WHEN [c].[Age]` calls were the confusion rather than the overall look of the query - which is why exact examples would make a solution more obvious.

Comment: Yea, it's a bit wonky looking, the SQL equivalent of `if((name == "Caius" ? true : false) == true)` but it might end up being optimized away to the same overall thing! :D

Comment: Ok, my example is bad.
Explanation: the important parts are expression creation and resulting SQL. Other things are just random examples, which are not even from the same query. They are there to roughly show, what is going on and is produced by the code. Unfortunately i can not show production code.

The Performance is an issue as the list of search criteria can have hundreds of `Property - Value` pairs. At 500 of them an Exception `SQL statement is to deeply nested` occurs. The resulting SQL script performs way worse than "normal" SQL would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `Expression.Or` is [bitwise or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.or?view=net-5.0), so basically `|` operator. And `Expression.And` is [bitwise and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.and?view=net-5.0) (`&`). So expression you have is:

```
c => (c.Name == "John" | c.Name == "Bob" ) & c.Age = 13;
```

What you want instead (how you would write it by hand) is this:

```
c => (c.Name == "John" || c.Name == "Bob" ) && c.Age = 13;
```

And for that you need to use `Expression.OrElse` and `Expression.AndAlso`:

```
foreach (var sc in searchCriteria){
    var orList = new List<Expression>();
    foreach (var value in sc.Value) {
        var expr = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, sc.Key),
            Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(value, typesDictionary[sc.Key]), typesDictionary[sc.Key]));
        orList.Add(expr);
    }
    andList.Add(orList.Aggregate(Expression.OrElse));
}
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(andList.Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso), param);
```

After that you should have more "normal" looking sql query generated.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try it tomorrow when i get back to the project and post a result.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It worked. The resulting SQL statement ist now as expected.
I still get `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries...` because combining several expression trees results in exessive amount of parentheses. Any idea how to solve this

Comment: My only idea is to collect all values for the same column in array and use Contains. So, instead of doing Name = John or Name = Bob or ... - use someArray.Contains(Name).

Comment: Yes, that was the way to go. It works with `.Contains()`, although it was tough to figure out, how to create a `List<T>` at runtime, when you only know what T is at runtime and extract the corresponding `.Contains` method.